# Compile error in define macro when using $bits

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

While writing the following macro, I am getting the compile error:

```
`define TEST1(out, in, sel)      \ \
  integer i;                      \ \
  always_comb begin                  \ \
    out = $bits(1'b0);               \\

    for(i=0; i<=$bits(sel); i=i+1)   \\
        out = out | ({$bits(out){sel[i]}} & in[i]);    \\
    end          ;
```

Error-msg:

```
near "[": syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or '}'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the blank line, and only use one backslash per line.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 22.5.1 *`define*:

> If more than one line is necessary to specify the text, the newline
> character shall be preceded by a backslash ( \ ). The first newline
> character not preceded by a backslash shall end the macro text.

```
`define TEST1(out, in, sel)      \
  integer i;                      \
  always_comb begin                  \
    out = $bits(1'b0);               \
    for(i=0; i<=$bits(sel); i=i+1)   \
        out = out | ({$bits(out){sel[i]}} & in[i]);    \
    end          ;
```